# antd URL is not supported - unsure what warning means, or how to solve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to learn React, so am following a tutorial on Youtube. With my code as it is, the live server is bringing up the errors shown below. I'm not really sure where to start with it.. Am I lacking a dependency or something? I'm not sure

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/config-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 61:4-74:5 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-28

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/icon/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 61:4-74:5 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-28

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/locale-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 61:4-74:5 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-28

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/time-picker/style/index.less' URL is not supported
 @ ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css 8:6-231 22:17-24 26:7-21 58:25-39 59:36-47 59:50-64 61:4-74:5 63:6-73:7 64:54-65 64:68-82 70:42-53 70:56-70 72:21-28 83:0-201 83:0-201 84:22-29 84:33-47 84:50-64
 @ ./src/index.js 8:0-28
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

Replace `import 'antd/dist/antd.css` with  `import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css`